# window.print() breaks on html video tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, video

My `window.print()` statements have been acting very strange and I finally narrowed it down to the videos in my html.  I'll clarify strange, the print dialog only pops up after a page refresh or after an alert(which I find bizarre), and subsequent clicks on the print button result in inconsistent and flaky firing of the print dialog.

If I move the video files out of the expected dir so the html can't find them or remove the video tags the print functionality works perfectly.  Currently the videos are sitting directly under the end of the jquery mobile content `</div>` tag, but I've tried moving them around in the page content with no change in behavior.

Has anyone encountered this problem or know how I might fix it?

EDIT: Tried grabbing the videos with jquery and calling `.remove()` on them to see if I could get it to fire properly on click but no go.

Comment: Working exclusively with chrome but just tested in firefox and got similar behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe @media property will be helpful?

Example that works for me (please note styles applied):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        @media print {
             video { display: none; }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body onload="window.print();">
    <h1>Sample Text</h1>
    <video width="320" height="240" controls>
        <source src="example_video_file.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
    <p>To be printed out</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I get the same behavior, if you're not actually loading a real video then it work, you have to load a video file.

Answer (score 0):

Calling this function as a workaround for this Chrome bug did the trick for me:

```
function printPage() {
    window.print();

    //workaround for Chrome bug - https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=141633
    if (window.stop) {
        location.reload(); //triggering unload (e.g. reloading the page) makes the Print dialog appear
        window.stop(); //immediately stop reloading
    }
    return false;
}
```